# Jenkins warning : Credentials from Kubernetes Secrets will not be available

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

when I logged in jenkins, there were many notifications and it was keeping on adding new notifications. Those won't go away until you restart Jenkins.

```
Failed to initialize Kubernetes secret provider
java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (kubernetes.default.svc)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)...
```

I'm not sure why is it complaining, can you give me some advices?

Comment: The error " No such host is known (kubernetes.default.svc) at" says it is not able to resolve kubernetes services as it is routable internal only

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been solved, because I accidentally installed k8S-related plug-ins, but I did not use these plug-ins, there was no reminder after uninstalling the plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Kubernetes Credentials Provider" plugin works.